# Maximize the angle subtended by the camera lens

Tags: calculus, geometry

> A photographer is taking a picture of a four-foot painting hung in an art gallery. The camera lens is 1 foot below the lower edge of the painting. How far should the camera be from the painting to maximize the angle subtended by the camera lens?

I have no idea this question is asking.  It is in the section about the derivative of inverse trigonometric functions.  Sorry, my English failed me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the rough sketch below, the painting is represented by the line $\overline{TB}$, which is $4$ feet long. The horizontal line passes one foot below $B$. The camera may be anywhere on that line; in the sketch it’s at $C$. The angle that you’re supposed to maximize is $\angle TCB$, the angle at the camera between the top and the bottom of the painting, and the distance that’s wanted is $|CW|$, the horizontal distance from the camera to the wall on which the painting is hung.

```
                                                   |T  
                                                   |  
                                                   |  
                                                   |B  

                      ____C________________________W
```